# Record User Interaction for a Tcl Tk Test Automation

Tags: user-interface, testing, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to do some tests on our tcl tk application regarding the user interaction. As the application has parts similar to a CAD for which every mouse movement is relevant, I would like to do something like record all events of some user interactions. My goal would be to playback these events laterwards and on every program change to discover potential changes. Or even better to assure the GUI behaves always the same and produces always the same data.

I know, that I can generate some enter motion and button events, but this would not be the same like the thousands of events generated by a real user interaction. But it is very important for me to have exactly these thousands of events.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Comment: Have you watched out for earlier conversations? At least the following seem relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3771683/how-to-test-a-tcl-tk-script, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258356/tcl-tk-automating-gui-testing, and for recording capabilities: http://wiki.tcl.tk/15726

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately they didn't help me. There are some interesting points mentioned at http://wiki.tcl.tk/15726, but many of the links are not valid any more, especially those, who might have helped.

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively easy to record events of particular types with `bind` — you'll find that `<ButtonPress>`, `<ButtonRelease>`, `<Enter>`, `<Leave>`, `<FocusIn>`, `<FocusOut>`, `<KeyPress>` and `<KeyRelease>` cover pretty much everything that you are interested in — and then play them back with `event generate`. (You need to record quite a bit of information about each event in order to regenerate it correctly, but the underlying model is that of X events with similar names.) Assuming you're not wanting to support inter-application cut-and-paste or drag-and-drop for the purposes of recording; those complicate things a lot. You'll likely have a lot of events; recording to an SQLite database might make a lot of sense.

However, you should think carefully about which parts of the application you want to record. Does it matter if the order of two buttons in the outer shell of the application outside the CAD-like area get swapped in order? For most users, provided you're clear about what the buttons do (through clear labels and icons) it isn't very important, but for replaying recorded events it can matter hugely. Instead, for the parts of the application that are simple buttons and edit fields, I'd *not* record the details of them but would instead just record when the buttons are clicked and the changes to the text content of entries and so on. In effect, it's capturing higher-level events, and that's much easier to replay correctly. It's only when the user is in that main CAD area that you need the full detail.

Also, beware of changes to *font sizes* and *screen sizes/scaling*. They can change how things are laid out and may happen because of system-level alterations outside the scope of your application.

Comment: I already tried to use `bind` in combination with `event generate`. But my approach was to have something general not bound to every single widget. Best without knowledge about the current implementation. I tried to use a new `toplevel` widget, positioned under the real application but with a grab on it and ungrabbing it to pass through the event. But even with `-when tail`  the grabbing is too slow. Maybe I really must limit the tracking to the CAD-like widgets.

Answer (score 0):

We started out the way you describe: record all those thousands of motion events, etc. Including exact timings which are extremely important for a GUI application as well.

It quickly became appearent that those recordings became too hard to maintain. They are also overly brittle in light of UI changes. Another problem where the hardcoded time values. A switch to a more powerful machine (or a cpu under load) would break the execution.

The two biggest improvements we introduced

- Event compression: recognize the *high-level* action the user wanted to perform (like selecting a menu item). The recorded  *activateItem* command would then perform the necessary work (event emulation) on replay.
- Synchronization functions: instead of relying on a particular timing commands like *waitForObject* wait for an object to come into existance and become ready for interaction.

It took several years for this to work fluently, however. Including a central Object Map repository, property and screenshot verifications, high-level test descriptions in BDD and others. Feel free to take a look a the [Squish for Tk](https://www.froglogic.com/squish/editions/automated-tk-gui-testing/) product that came out of this work.